# VSTS build fails but portal shows successful deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

Sorry, less a code issue but a process issue in deploying through Microsoft VSTS. I'm deploying an ARM template via a VSTS build definition and it failed (complaining the storage account was not in the same RG as the VM ).. BUT in the azure portal against the RG it shows a successful deployment and the resources deployed as expected.

What would cause VSTS to report an issue this way? Obvious issue is my deployment technically fails as a VSTS job despite being fine in Azure.

Comment: share the process? share the template? share the error?

Comment: Set/add system.debug variable to true and queue build or start release, then post the detail log here. (Remove personal information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with no changes is stopped erroring so i'm guessing something on the azure side. Thanks anyway